# How can I replace a value of a map with another map?

Tags: dictionary, object, dart

I'm trying to re-assign a value of a map with another map. In this example, I'm trying to copy the definition of `address` into `billing_address`

```
    test("test dart", () {
      Map<String, dynamic> baseSchema = {
        r"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
        "definitions": {
          "address": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "street_address": {"type": "string"},
              "city": {"type": "string"},
              "state": {"type": "string"}
            },
            "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
          }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "billing_address": {r"$ref": "#/definitions/address"},
          "shipping_address": {r"$ref": "#/definitions/address"}
        }
      };
      baseSchema["properties"]["billing_address"] =
          Map<String, dynamic>.from(baseSchema["definitions"]["address"]);

      print(baseSchema);
    });
```

This crashes with the following:

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>' of 'value'
```

I have tried adding `Map<String, dynamic>.from(other)` in places and changing the type of the schema to `dynamic` but can't get it to work